# Is there any way to get a page url using metafields in shopify?

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I m trying to make a `<a>` tag in product page which redirects to other pages, I want to give this url using metafield any idea on how to archive this?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

`<a href ="[LINK]" ></a>`

Copy the link you need, and put it instead of [LINK]

Comment: it does but i need it through metafeilds since every product is gonna have it different link

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple. Assuming you have your URL in a metafield, just render the value into the href.

```
<a href="{{ someresource.metafields.mylinks.url }}" />
```

Since you did not specify which resource you speak of, I left it as someresource. If it is pages, the use pages. **mylinks** is your namespace where you stored your metafield key values. The key is **url**, and the value is whatever you stored there, a link to another page maybe.

Shopify has a ton of documentation on using Metafields, you can refer to those for more details.